# you tube live streaming api not stream the video

Tags: youtube-api, streaming, live-streaming

I checked for the youtube live streaming api and it provides the facility for stream the video over the youtube.

- But how can we access it in the development?
- How can we use this api (youtube live streaming) and stream the video in the youtube?

Answer (score 0):

You will have to enable "Live" streaming feature in your account. Looks like you will have to be eligible to have it enabled.

http://www.youtube.com/live/all

If its enables, you can push your pre-recorded video files/live video to the google's publishing point. For that you can use any supported media encoders. More info can be read here on how to set it up.

https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/2907883?hl=en&ref_topic=2853713

Once thats setup, you can stream events as if its a real live event !